# Cannot log in after changing permissions with owncloud script

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, raspbian

I am trying to install owncloud and had some issues with permissions in `/var/www/html/`. One site suggested to run a script which changes the permission, and it looked ok to me so I ran it as root in the directory /home/owncloud.

```
ocpath='/home/owncloud'
htuser='www-data'
htgroup='www-data'
rootuser='root'

printf "Creating possible missing Directories\n"
mkdir -p $ocpath/data
mkdir -p $ocpath/assets
mkdir -p $ocpath/updater

printf "chmod Files and Directories\n"
find ${ocpath}/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0640
find ${ocpath}/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0750

printf "chown Directories\n"
chown -R ${rootuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/apps/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/assets/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/config/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/data/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/themes/
chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/updater/

chmod +x ${ocpath}/occ

printf "chmod/chown .htaccess\n"
if [ -f ${ocpath}/.htaccess ]
 then
  chmod 0644 ${ocpath}/.htaccess
  chown ${rootuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/.htaccess
fi
if [ -f ${ocpath}/data/.htaccess ]
 then
  chmod 0644 ${ocpath}/data/.htaccess
  chown ${rootuser}:${htgroup} ${ocpath}/data/.htaccess
fi
```

[source](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html#strong-perms-label)

However, something must have gone terribly wrong, and I got plenty of errors in the style of `chmod: changing permissions of 'xxx': Operation not permitted`.

Now I can't even log in any more using ssh:

```
ssh -p 1234 user@fakeraspi.ddns.net
user@fakeraspi.ddns.net's password: 
/bin/bash: Permission denied
```

Two questions: What could have possibly gone wrong? And less important: Is there a way to fix this (it's a test server, so no harm if I have to restore from a backup).

Comment: Just to verify I understand the situation: the inability to log in is just limited to users whose home directory equal to or under /home/ownclowd?  Are there any symlinks under /home/ownclowd that point to outside of /home/owncloud?

Comment: Just to clarify my question about symlinks - `chown -R` does not follow symlinks, unless they're specified on the command line.  If one of the directories chown was explicitly called on was actually a symlink to / or to /etc, that would prevent anyone from logging into the box except the user who now owned /etc and all the files contained within it.  This would also happen if somehow ocpath was not set in this script and rootuser was set to something besides root, but it clearly is set at the beginning, so unless that file was changed, that's not what happened.

Comment: @EdGrimm turns out, there was a spelling mistake in ocpath, `ocpath='/home/owcnloud'`, which does not exist. This is what went wrong.

Comment: I would've though the `mkdir -p` command would have taken care of that.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT good point...

Comment: Are you able to log into the terminal or the server console via root?

Answer (score 0):

what could have happened:  the variable ocpath was misspelled causing

```
find ${ocpath}/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0640
```

to be interpreted as

```
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0640
```

rather than

```
find /home/owncloud/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0640
```

For example:

```
$ cat example.sh



cpath='/var/www/owncloud'
find ${ocpath}/ -type f -print0 

$ ./example.sh | head

find: /Quarantine: Permission denied
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
```

To fix this, if you can login via console into single user mode you could run a fix permissions script like so:

```
echo '
chmod -R 755 /bin /boot /dev /etc/ /home /lib /lib64 \
/media /mnt /opt /run /sbin /srv /usr /var

chmod -R 777 /initrd.img /vmlinuz
chmod -R 1777 /tmp
chmod -R 555 /sys
chmod -R 555 /proc
chmod -R 700 /root

' > fixpermission

chmod +x fixpermission

./fixpermission
```

But yeah, you may wan't to just blow it away.  In the future test any script that recursively chmod's by echo until your satisfied its the correct directories, then run chmod.   We've all been burned by this :D